# Unable to upload and process image with CarrierWave and MiniMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

I am trying to implement image-upload with CarrierWave and MiniMagick. I was able to upload an image with carrierwave, but when I implemented MiniMagick to resize uploaded images, it returned this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT in ItemsController#create

No such file or directory - identify -ping /var/folders/6y/j8zfcgmd02x5s439c0np8fjh0000gn/T/mini_magick20121228-71203-bdoeul.jpg
```

image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
  end

end
```

I have imagemagick installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what went wrong, but after I uninstalled MacPort and all its ports, installed Homebrew and reinstalled ImageMagick, everything works as expected.